# Is WS-Adressing time consuming in cxf?

Tags: cxf

I'm trying to tune a cxf-based webservice. By activating the logging I came across these lines:

```
2016-05-19 16:33:37,956;DEBUG;org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain;Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.WrappedOutInterceptor@384d0499
2016-05-19 16:33:37,956;DEBUG;org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain;Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareOutInterceptor@78c615ba
2016-05-19 16:33:37,956;DEBUG;org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.ContextUtils;retrieving MAPs from context property javax.xml.ws.addressing.context.inbound
2016-05-19 16:33:37,957;DEBUG;org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.ContextUtils;WS-Addressing - failed to retrieve Message Addressing Properties from context
2016-05-19 16:33:37,976;DEBUG;org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain;Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor@10bed1a8
```

Between line 4 and 5 it takes 19ms, which is about 20% of the whole request time. So my question is: What causes this gap? And how can I avoid this?
The log says that WS-Addressing is failing. Can I disable WS-Addressing?

**Update**

I'm using the CXFNonSpringServlet with the following lines to set up the service:

```
EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, impl);
endpoint.setWsdlLocation("...");
endpoint.setAddress("...");
endpoint.setServiceName(new QName("..."));
endpoint.setEndpointName(new QName("..."));
endpoint.publish();
```

Comment: The 19ms appear **after** the failed message, so I don't think it's a problem with ws addressing. How is your service configured? Do you use WS-Policy? Then you should look for the <Addressing> expression. If not WS-Addressing should be disabled by default if the feature is not explicitly enabled as the [docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-addressing.html) say.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But if it's not the WS-Adressing then the 19ms are used by the BareOutInterceptor to do the databinding, right?

Comment: The last entry mentions `SoapOutInterceptor$SoapOutEndingInterceptor`. Could be anywhere between addressing and this last interceptor. Best way to find out which steps are involved is debugging the processing by setting a breakpoint in PhaseInterceptorChain. But after all 19ms do not seem that long to have a real impact on performance. Can you reproduce and verify this behaviour?